# ./configure, syntax error: unexpected token (lighttpd)

Tags: debian, configure, lighttpd, pkg-config

I want to build a modified version of lighttpd.
I follow this tutorial:

[Downloading and building the H264 Streaming Module for Lighttpd (version 2)](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Lighttpd-Version2)

This is what I've done so far:

```
apt get install lighttpd
apt get install automake autoconf libtool 
cd /var/tmp
wget http://h264.code-shop.com/download/lighttpd-1.4.18_mod_h264_streaming-2.2.9.tar.gz
tar -zxvf lighttpd-1.4.18_mod_h264_streaming-2.2.9.tar.gz
wget http://download.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/releases-1.4.x/lighttpd-1.4.28.tar.gz
tar ...
```

After I copied all files and data to the directory and Makefile.am I entered:

```
./autogen.sh


./autogen.sh: running `libtoolize --copy --force'
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
libtoolize: copying file `./ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
libtoolize: copying file `m4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
./autogen.sh: running `aclocal -I m4'
./autogen.sh: running `autoheader'
./autogen.sh: running `automake --add-missing --copy --foreign'
Makefile.am:8: lib_LTLIBRARIES must be set with `=' before using `+='

./configure --enable-maintainer-mode --prefix=${HOME}/test/lighttpd-1.4.28
```

The console returns:

```
    ...
        checking for pkg-config... no
        checking for libev support... ./configure: line 12184: syntax error near unexpected token `LIBEV,'
./configure: line 12184: `      PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBEV, libev, ,'
root@foo...
```

Some people solved this by installing "pkg-config". I installed this package but I still can't run the configuration.

EDIT: this is the source of the configure file at this line

```
LIBEV_CFLAGS=""
LIBEV_LIBS=""

    if test "$WITH_LIBEV" != "no"; then
            PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBEV, libev, ,
                    dnl no pkg-config for libev, searching manually:

                    if test "$WITH_LIBEV" != "yes"; then
                            LIBEV_CFLAGS="-I$WITH_LIBEV/include"
                            LIBEV_LIBS="-L$WITH_LIBEV/lib -lev"
  else

          AC_CHECK_HEADERS([ev.h],[
                                AC_CHECK_LIB([ev], [ev_loop], [
                                                LIBEV_CFLAGS=""
                                                LIBEV_LIBS="-lev"
                                        ],[
                                        AC_MSG_ERROR([libev not found])
                                        ]
                                )],[
                                        AC_MSG_ERROR([libev not found])
                                ]
                        )
                fi
        )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lighttpd-1.4.28 is not very current. You may be suffering from [lighttpd bug #2300](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/2300) *Libev-4.0 isn't detected by lighttpd-1.x*, this was fixed in 1.4.29 (backport from 2.0).

Otherwise, try:

- double check your dependencies (specifically required versions of `autoconf` etc) as documented on the h264.code-shop.com instructions
- make sure you can build `lighttpd` from source *without* the h264 module so that you can eliminate one problem at a time

Comment: I was able to build lighttpd-1.4.18 without any problems, so I assume you're right. I will download a newer version

Comment: I just built 1.4.30. thank you very much dude.